# OpenCart inaccessible over LAN

Tags: php, opencart

I installed OpenCart today on a vm under Linux.
On the LAN it works fine. 
I opened the port 80 on router but when I try to load my website from external URL, it loads only the text without image and template. Where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: Did you set the right URL in your openchart settings?

Comment: Hi John, do you mean in the files config.php and admin/config.php?

Comment: I dont know. just make sure openchart outputs your external url in the code, so CSS files are called the right way and not like: `src='http://192.168.0.5/style.css'`

Comment: Thanks a lot John, it works now! It's a strange configuration on OpenCart but it works fine. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is showing but missing stuff you will need to set the address as an ip not localhost. This is done in your config.php file. Change all of the localhost values to the ip, save and refresh